# Read text file from Google drive in Next JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am looking for a way of reading a text file from Google Drive. I have been able to list all the files that a user has but I'm having problem reading it.

```
const listFiles = (searchTerm = null) => {
    setIsFetchingGoogleDriveFiles(true);
    gapi.client.drive.files
      .list({
        pageSize: 10,
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        setIsFetchingGoogleDriveFiles(false);
        setListDocumentsVisibility(true);
        const res = JSON.parse(response.body);
        console.log(res.files);
        setDocuments(res.files);
      });
  };
```